# cifs-mount with multiple shared folders on windows server

Tags: mount, windows, samba, cifs, shared-folders

I'm having a windows server `winserv` with several shared folders `share1`, `share2`, etc. and would like to `cifs`-mount them all in the terminal by just addressing the server and not each shared folder individually.

While I can successfully use my graphical file explorer `dolphin` to search the network for `winserver`, log in and have all shared folders listed, OR mount each shared folder separately from the terminal by using

```
mount.cifs -o user=winuser //winserv/share1 /mnt/share1
<password prompt>
#trailing slash after share does not affect the mount:
mount.cifs -o user=winuser //winserv/share2/ /mnt/share2
<password prompt>
```

I cannot mount `winserv` directly and have all shared folders listed. I.e. this is unsuccessful:

```
mount.cifs -o user=winuser //winserv /mnt/allshares
#I also tried a trailing slash, but to no effect
mount.cifs -o user=winuser //winserv/ /mnt/allshares
```

The resulting error message is:

```
Retrying with upper case share name
mount error(6): No such device or address
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
```

So how can I mount them all at once just like `dolphin` does?

Comment: You can't mount all shares at one time via command line mount, but you can do that using a script... here you can have an example https://hardc0l2e.wordpress.com/2011/08/17/mount-all-available-cifs-shares-using-gvfs/

Comment: But how does dolphin search the folders then? It surely is based on an sbm-command?